# How to create custom flash advertisment in Google?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, google-ads, flash

Can we create custom flash advertisement for Google ad-sense? like yahoo does? I tried on my adwords account but there is no way except followings,

1) Upload custom image advertisement.

2) Update the Google flash templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google as far as I know does not have a inbuilt flash maker that will convert a series of images and sound to a Flash Compatible file, so with this said you will need to make your own. When you upload a image to Adwords you can see it says 'Acceptable Formats: PNG, JPEG, [SWF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) and so on.. the important file format to take notice off here is .swf - this is a [flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) based file.

A lot of people use [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash-builder.html) and [Adobe Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash.html) when designing flash files for adwords through there are cheaper alternatives that I'll let you explore for yourself using [the good old Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Flash%20banner%20maker).

Adwords will however convert your flash to HTML5 compatible devices [Source](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722096?hl=en):

> AdWords can convert Flash to HTML5, which can be viewed on most major
>   desktops, tablets, and mobile devices. The converted ad may not be
>   100% identical to the Flash ad you created, so be sure to preview it
>   before saving. Most shapes, embedded fonts, timeline animation, text,
>   movie clips, buttons, and scripting are supported, but not filters or
>   blending. The system automatically determines which version of your ad
>   to show, based on the device that your customer is using.